# Delta functions for surface of non trivial shapes

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions, geometry, differential-equations, dirac-delta-distributions

Say I'm trying to solve Laplace's equation on an object that isn't a sphere or a trivially characterized surface. I will want to solve:
$$\nabla^2G\left(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}'\right)=-4\pi\delta\left(f\left(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}'\right)\right).$$

For an example, take a cube of side $a$. How can I express the right hand side of the above equation such that it vanishes everywhere but on the surface of the cube.